# Ajuda com query Select no MySql

Tags: mysql

Tenho a tabela "clientes" e tenho outra com o nome de "produtos". Cada cliente possui diversos produtos onde as tuplas da tabela produtos tem o id do cliente para fazer a referência.

Preciso de um Select que me retorne todos os clientes que possuam o produto de código 19 mas não possuam o produto de código 22.

Realizei algumas tentativas aqui com Select aninhado mas não consegui o resultado.

Poderiam me auxiliar a montar esta consulta?

**Tabela Clientes:**

- IDCLIENTE
- NOME

**Tabela Produtos Clientes:**

- IDTABELA
- IDPRODUTO
- IDCLIENTE

Tentei implementar a seguinte lógica:

```
select
    IDCLIENTE,
    IDPRODUTO
from
    CLIENTES C
    inner join PRODUTOS_CLIENTES P on C.IDCLIENTE = P.IDCLIENTE
where
    P.IDPRODUTO not in (
        select
            IDPRODUTO
        from
            PRODUTOS_CLIENTES
        where
            IDPRODUTO <> 19
            and IDPRODUTO <> 22
    )
```

Com isso consegui todos os registros de clientes que possuem esses 2 produtos, queria agora desse resultado retirar os que tem o código 22.

Comment: Mostre como estão as tabelas.  Poste como você está tentando fazer para ficar mais fácil.

Comment: tentou fazendo com uma juncao completa removendo os produtos no where? `SELECT * FROM CLIENTES
    INNER JOIN PRODUTOS ON PRODUTOS.CLIENTE_ID = CLIENTES.ID
    WHERE PRODUTOS.CODIGO = 19 AND PRODUTOS.CODIGO <> 22`

Comment: @LeonardoPaim quando for acrescentar dados sobre sua pergunta, edite a pergunta e poste nela. Nos comentários vira uma bagunça e complica a visualização.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isso resolveria o seu problema:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES
WHERE CLIENTES.IDCLIENTE IN
   (SELECT IDCLIENTE FROM PRODUTOS_CLIENTES
   WHERE IDPRODUTO = 19)
AND CLIENTES.IDCLIENTE NOT IN
   (SELECT IDCLIENTE FROM PRODUTOS_CLIENTES
   WHERE IDPRODUTO = 22)
```